# Вопрос по редиректам

Tags: php, .htaccess

Пробовал в .htaccess делать.
Есть путь site.ru/ourproduct/. Хочу сделать редирект на site.ru/products/
Прописываю 301 редирект. Всё нормально. Но другие страницы соответсвенно, которые идут site.ru/ourproduct/page1...page n также начинают редиректить и ломаются. Как решить эту проблему?Чтобы только для /ourproduct/ работал редирект, а для остальных не работал?

Answer (score 0):

Указываете прямой путь к файлу

```
Redirect 301 https://site.ru/ourproduct/index.html https://site.ru/products/
```